# Extracting Images with PDFBox - Images being split into strips

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox to extract the images out of a PDF. My code is based on the example provided by PDFBox, [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/ExtractImages.java).

However, some images are being extracted as a number of horizontal 'strips', i.e. a single image in the PDF is extracted as 5 (for example) images that need stitching back together to form the whole image.

Why is this happening, and how do I stop it happening so I can extract the full single image?

Comment: **Please provide a sample PDF to analyze.** This being said, I have seen PDFs which actually contained multiple images which were arranged seamlessly on the page content to give the impression of a single image. In such a case PDFBox image extraction will rightfully return multiple images.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't provide a sample, as the PDFs I'm working on contain confidential information. I'll try and see if I can replicate it somehow. The images would have been inserted as a single image though - so unless they have been split up by Office on export to PDF that's not the case.